# Rails ActiveRecord group by time but pad dates with nil values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I'm using activerecord to get the count of items for a certain day:

```
Item.group("date(created_at)").count.values
```

But this doesn't give me `0` if there are no records for a given day, how can I fix this? Or is there are more "Rails" way do to something like this?

Any help is hugely appreciated, thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a GROUP BY query, you are going to get groups based on the records that exist, so if there are no records with a given value in the grouping column, there will be no groups for that value.  The database does not psychically know to add in other date values that you might be interested in.

What I would do to get what you want is create a new Hash with a default value of `0` and then merge the result of your query into that.  When you subsequently try to retrieve any value from that Hash for which there is no entry, you'll get 0 as the result.

Edit: Remove `.values`

```
date_counts = Hash.new(0)
date_counts.merge! Item.group("date(created_at)").count
```

Alternatively, if you want to make sure there are entries in the Hash for every date in a range, so you can iterate over those, ...

```
date_counts = {}
(Date.civil(2010,1,1)...Date.civil(2010,2,1)).each do |date|
  date_counts[date]=0
end
date_counts.merge! Item.group("date(created_at)").count
```

---

**Update**

Here is some output when I pass my date range and model into here, oddly enough it gets different length hashes:

```
{Sun, 01 May 2011=>0, Mon, 02 May 2011=>0, Tue, 03 May 2011=>0, Wed, 04 May 2011=>0, Thu, 05 May 2011=>0, Fri, 06 May 2011=>0, Sat, 07 May 2011=>0, Sun, 08 May 2011=>0, Mon, 09 May 2011=>0, Tue, 10 May 2011=>0, Wed, 11 May 2011=>0, Thu, 31 Mar 2011=>2, Sun, 03 Apr 2011=>1, Fri, 08 Apr 2011=>643, Sat, 09 Apr 2011=>2360, Sun, 10 Apr 2011=>705, Mon, 11 Apr 2011=>34}
{Sun, 01 May 2011=>0, Mon, 02 May 2011=>0, Tue, 03 May 2011=>0, Wed, 04 May 2011=>0, Thu, 05 May 2011=>0, Fri, 06 May 2011=>0, Sat, 07 May 2011=>0, Sun, 08 May 2011=>0, Mon, 09 May 2011=>0, Tue, 10 May 2011=>0, Wed, 11 May 2011=>0, Sat, 02 Apr 2011=>1, Fri, 08 Apr 2011=>4158, Sat, 09 Apr 2011=>12206, Sun, 10 Apr 2011=>4279, Mon, 11 Apr 2011=>169}
{Sun, 01 May 2011=>0, Mon, 02 May 2011=>0, Tue, 03 May 2011=>0, Wed, 04 May 2011=>0, Thu, 05 May 2011=>0, Fri, 06 May 2011=>0, Sat, 07 May 2011=>0, Sun, 08 May 2011=>0, Mon, 09 May 2011=>0, Tue, 10 May 2011=>0, Wed, 11 May 2011=>0}
```

Not sure whats causing it... hmm.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm getting: `TypeError: can't convert Array into Hash`, happens for `merge!', strange... is this what happened to you?

Comment: I was assuming that the Arel syntax you used was equivalent to <model>.count(:group=>:created_at) which would return an ordered Hash, but perhaps those are not equivalent.

Comment: Oh -- wait.  I copied your `.values`, but that would lose the date keys.  Editing...

Comment: It strange, because I get differing hash lengths for different arrays, I updated my question, any ideas what would cause this?

Comment: It looks like the groups you're getting back from your find include dates that are outside of the range that we're merging into, so those are added as new entries rather than replacing existing ones.  You should presumably add criteria to restrict the date range that you're requesting.